# Entity Framework Migrations with same name

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have a problem.

Using Entity Framework code first and when merging code between branches we sometimes have to create empty migrations using

```
add-migration name -ignorechanges
```

The issue here is that a developer has created migrations on two different branches using the same name.  They have different date stamps, so the file names don't conflict, but the generated class names are the same.  Each migration has been applied to the databases on their respective environments.

I'm now merging the two branches together and, because the class names are the same, the project now won't compile.

No idea what to do.  Any ideas please?

Thanks

Comment: What's the  compilation error? Usually a botched migration just results in a run time model error. See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn481501(v=vs.113).aspx) for info on team environment issues.

Comment: The error is that the two migrations, even though they have different filenames, result in the same class.

Comment: In the end, as they are empty migrations, I was able to resolve by deleting one of the migration files from the project and removing the corresponding record from the database migrations table.